# Is there a way to modify arccosine range in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Currently if you use `math.acos()` or `numpy.arccos()` they both return values in `[0, pi]`.

```
numpy.arccos([1, -1])
array([ 0.        ,  3.14159265])
```

Is there a way to modify this range? For instance, to force `numpy.arccos()` to look in `[6pi, 7pi]`?

For instance, cos(0.387799014) = cos(2061.27258) = 0.925743608. I need `numpy.arccos` to look in `[656pi, 657pi]` and return `2061.27258` which is the first value in this range that solves the equation. However if you run `numpy.arccos(0.925743608)` it returns `0.387799014` which is the first value in `[0, pi]` that solves the equation.

Comment: It's a periodic function, yeah? Why not just add 6pi (or whatever other multiple) to the result?

Comment: Thanks Karl, I am wondering if there is any way to modify this range in the libraries I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the numpy `numpy.arccos()` documentation,

"The convention is to return the angle z whose real part lies in [0, pi]."

As such, No, it's not possible.

Another way to solve it (as suggested in the comments), multiply the output by the wanted amount.